# How is it possible to add an icon on the right title of a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, icons, android-dialogfragment

I am currently working with a DialogFragment, but I cannot set an icon on the top right corner.

I have seen some tricks to display the icon as a Dialog icon:

```
 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Dialog myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info)
     .setTitle(title)
  return myDialog;
 }
```

but this would not help as the icon is on the left side and is not intuitive to click

I know that I could set a custom layout, but I would be sure that the layout would reflect all the OS and OEM manufacturer customizations (same style)

Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question and it has most likely been solved but maybe someone finds it useful.

On your onCreateView method do something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    // your view related code, inflate or whatever
    ...
```

This prepares the title view with the continer to set the icon but it won't exist until after the view hierarchy has been instanced so you need to set the icon on a method that is called after that, like onActivityCreated, something like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     getDialog().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}
```

Be sure to call the super method first or your icon can be overriden.

Hope this helps someone...

Greetings from the Mexico...

Comment: A question is never too old for an answer :) I was wondering, why not add the icon in the xml for the DialogFragment itself? Is this possible?